# Why does the value of BASH_SUBSHELL not change while the value of SHLVL changes?

Tags: bash

The bash manual says

> **BASH_SUBSHELL**  Incremented by one within each subshell or subshell environment when the shell begins executing in that environment. The
>   initial value is 0.
>
> **SHLVL** Incremented by one each time a new instance of Bash is started. This is intended to be a count of how deeply your Bash shells
>   are nested.

What are the differences between the two builtin variables?

Specifically what differences are between "subshell or subshell environment" and "Bash shells"?

In the following example, why does the value of `BASH_SUBSHELL` not change, while the value of `SHLVL` changes?

```
$ echo $BASH_SUBSHELL
0
$ echo $SHLVL
1
$ bash
$ echo $BASH_SUBSHELL
0
$ echo $SHLVL
2
```

Answer (score 3):

this refer to subshell within main shell

compare

```
echo "a" $BASH_SUBSHELL "b" $SHLVL
```

with

```
( echo "a" $BASH_SUBSHELL "b" $SHLVL )
```

or

```
( ( echo "a" $BASH_SUBSHELL "b" $SHLVL ) )
```

this might be useful inside function if you set env var.